# Xamarin Microsoft Oxford Vision problem with text recognize

Tags: android, xamarin, text, computer-vision

I have a problem with text recognition from receipts using Microsoft Oxford Vision with Xamarin.Forms.

Here is a code:

```
private async void BtnTake_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await TakePic();

            Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => photo.GetStream());

            var result = client.RecognizeTextAsync(photo.GetStream()).Result;
            var words = from r in result.Regions
                        from l in r.Lines
                        from w in l.Words
                        select w.Text;

            OutputText = string.Join(" ", words.ToArray());

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TextFromPhoto(OutputText, Image));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OutputText = "Ops! Something wrong!" + ex.ToString();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TextFromPhoto(OutputText, Image));
        }
    }

    private async Task<MediaFile> TakePic()
    {
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
        });

        return file;
    }
```

Code is perfectly working with normal text, like book photo page what i was took in application, but when i'm trying to use this to scan text from **receipt** program doesn't know what to do and on output we can see "513nlkm nlmnl l1mk 531" or something like that.

Photo when i have "normal" text:

[image]

Photo when i have receipt text:

[image]

Are there any proven ways to fix this?

Comment: Can you include an example of the image that is not scanned correctly?

Comment: Included example photos

Comment: @Jason look at this